# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to upload a file in reactjs, I want to display in the console, but when I click on upload button it gives me

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

this.state = {
  selectedFile: null
};

this.fileSelectedHandler = this.fileSelectedHandler.bind(this);
}

fileSelectedHandler(event) {
  this.setState({
    selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
  })
}

handleUpload() {
  console.log(this.state.selectedFile)
}
render() {
 return (
    <div class="group">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler} />
      <button onClick={this.handleUpload}> Upload </button>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I am getting the error at: `console.log(this.state.selectedFile)`

Comment: You have to bind `handleUpload` to `this` in the constructor the same way you do with your `fileSelectedHandler` method.

Comment: Are you calling the constructor function and super method before you declare the state?

Comment: you sloppy copy-pasted your code with just half of constructor

Comment: Okay, guys, I made an update I forgot to put constructor function and super method, now I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this either bind handleUpload to the correct this content or define your function in below format

```
handleUpload = () => {
console.log(this.state.selectedFile)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bro it worked!